# how can i keep an element animated using css keyframes animation

Tags: html, css, image, animation, slideshow

I'm trying to make images animated using keyframes
those images are in one div which is set to overflow-x: scroll and those images are displayed in flex on row direction, So what I want is to move those element in left side then instead of coming back from the left side I want that it come back from the right side, This is what I tried, but when I do keyframes like that, it goes in margin-left -100% then instead of coming back from the right it come back from the left.

```css
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow {
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.mySlides {
  cursor: all-scroll;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 .5rem;
}

.mySlides img {
  width: 50vh;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-container slide_2">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190747/800x600" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-container slide_3">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-container slide_4">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190747/800x600" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-container slide_5">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-container slide_6">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190757/800x600" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add images from for example placeholder.com so we have a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I've add images in placeholder you can run the snippet now

Comment: Do you have a demonstration of how the image should appear from the right? And after it comes from the right, where should it be placed i.e. at the end of the last image or back to its original position?

Comment: No @samir I don't have it. But what I want is to make them animated like how information are going at the bottom in news channel Tv

Comment: Basically continuous movement from left to right, correct?

Comment: Yes! that Is what I want

Comment: Will only one image move or all 5 images?

Comment: Yes I want all five it will be better

Comment: @ThierryMugisha Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make all images slide, we need to wrap them in a container and then we will animate this container as a whole using the `transform: translateX` property.

In keyframes, `translateX(0)` is the initial position which we will take to `-100%` for the outer container `slide` to hide to left. Now, to start it from right, we have to set the `translateX(100%)` and bring it to `0` so that the content moves from right to left.

```css
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow {
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  animation: 5s move 5s linear;
}

.mySlides {
  cursor: all-scroll;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.mySlides img {
  width: 50vh;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50.01% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <!-- Wrapper container -->
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slideshow-container slide_2">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190747/800x600" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-container slide_3">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-container slide_4">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190747/800x600" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-container slide_5">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/800x600" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-container slide_6">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190757/800x600" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```